# angular.less @import works but 404 in console on get imported file

Tags: css, angularjs, less

I am using AngularJS with angular.less. Having centralised my constants in one .less file, I import it using relative path at the top of my less files:

```
@import "constants"
```

While it obviously works, I get an error in the console, a 404 on a GET:

```
less.min.js:13 GET http://localhost:8000/constants.less 404 (Not Found)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the absolute path to the resource fixes the issue

```
@import "/assets/styles/constants";
```